# carrier wave not loading default image url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run rails in production mode , I put the default url of avatar in assets/images and made it like this :

```
"/assets/" + [version_name, "image.jpeg"].compact.join('_')
```

it works perfevtly in development mode but in production it doesn't and I don't know why also I have pre compiled assets but still so hope you help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path of your asset is:

```
/assets/v1_image.png
```

Then it will perfectly work fine in development if you used something like:

```
<img src="/assets/v1_image.png" />
```

Because in development assets are not precompiled by Rails asset pipeline.

But in production the asset pipeline will compile your assets and stamp it with some md5hash so your file name will end-up to be like:

```
/assets/v1_image-aee4be71f1288037ae78b997df388332edfd246471b533dcedaa8f9fe156442b.png
```

So the correct way to use it should be something like:

```
<img src="/assets/v1_image-aee4be71f1288037ae78b997df388332edfd246471b533dcedaa8f9fe156442b.png" />
```

but still this md5 hash will change from a deployment to another so the rails way to handle this is to use `image_path`, `image_url` or `image_tag` helpers from `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` to generate the correct path for you as follows:

---

`image_tag('v1_image.png')` will return:

```
<img src="/assets/v1_image-aee4be71f1288037ae78b997df388332edfd246471b533dcedaa8f9fe156442b.png" />
```

---

`image_path('v1_image.png')` will return:

```
/assets/v1_image-aee4be71f1288037ae78b997df388332edfd246471b533dcedaa8f9fe156442b.png
```

---

`image_url('v1_image.png')` will return:

```
http://www.example.com/assets/v1_image-aee4be71f1288037ae78b997df388332edfd246471b533dcedaa8f9fe156442b.png
```

I hope this is clear enough and can fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to `/assets` interfering with rails asset pipeline.

Please post your code for a better understanding of the question